# Terminal in cPanel is giving an error on launch: Error: The WebSocket handshake failed at 7:45:2

Tags: websocket, composer-php, cpanel

I need to run composer, but soon as I open Terminal from the cPanel, an error notification pops up saying that the web socket handshake failed.

I hit the reconnect button, and the second identical error pops up.

[image: Error on opening cPanel Terminal]

How should I get around this error? I'm not really familiar with Terminal on cPanel, or with Websockets, so appreciate a considerate reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar error and solved it by logging in to the cPanel using https://example.com/cpanel or https://ipaddress:2083 instead. Login again and try reconnecting to the terminal.

If it still doesn't work, [this article](https://www.ethernetservers.com/clients/knowledgebase/224/The-WebSocket-handshake-failed-when-using-the-cPanel-Terminal.html) suggests trying other web browsers. Also, make sure to disconnect from any VPN you might be connected to.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I fetch this issue. Solve issue by Cpanel Shared IP address.
Example: https://70.32.23.83:2083
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used example.com/cpanel instead of cpanel.example.com to login to cpanel and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once while inadvertently using vpn to connect.

This happened to me once when I inadvertently connected to my cpanel using a vpn. The issue went away after I disconnected vpn. A possible solution might be to turn off your vpn. Thank you, Ram!

Comment: I see, let me be more explicit then... This happened to me once when I inadvertently connected to my cpanel using a vpn. The issue went away after I disconnected vpn. A possible solution might be to turn off your vpn. Thank you, Ram!

Comment: Thanks @yodele! However I'm not using a VPN to connect. Nor am I using TOR either.

Answer (score 0):

offing vpn worked for me aftering spenting time thinking.